How to handle conflict between virtual destructor and "Rule of 0"?
"Rule of 0" says that we should not declare destructors, copy/move-constructors, and copy/move-assignments for classes that do not manage resources ownership.
But, when we create a base class, we need to declare a virtual destructor for the sake of proper destruction behavior of descendants.
Then, the question is: When a base class is not devised to manage resources, what should we do?

You only need a virtual destructor if you plan to use your object polymorphically.  Is your classed designed to be used that way?

If you don't actually have any resources to manage, just make it defaulted: virtual ~my_class() = default;

@Someprogrammerdude That's not the perfect solution. If I only declare a defaulted virtual destructor, then the Base's move constructor and move assignment will be deleted (although copy constructor/assignment are still supported but they are branded as deprecated), and all Derived classes' move constructors/assignments will be deleted(as no these two default methods of the Base exist).

@NathanOliver I should do more than just declaring a virtual destructor. See my response to Someprogrammerdude for details.

@SZYoo you can design a class that is intended to be a base class, but isn't intended to be held in an owning pointer, e.g. std::true_type

That stating of the rule of zero lacks nuance1.
You should prefer to define none of the five, but if you do define any of them, you should define all of them.
For a polymorphic base class Base, it's a fairly easy. ~Base has to be defined, because you need it to be virtual. As it turns out, you want to think about copying and moving, because they generally aren't appropriate. What should a Derived1 instance do to copy (or move from) a Derived2 instance?
So you end up with:
// No copy or moves allowed
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    Base(const Base&) = delete;
    Base(Base&&) = delete;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = delete;
    Base& operator=(Base&&) = delete;
};

// Subclasses can allow copy or move
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
protected:
    Base(const Base&) = default;
    Base(Base&&) = default;
    Base& operator=(const Base&) = default;
    Base& operator=(Base&&) = default;
};


You could, at a stretch, express that "the most derived type of the object" is a resource that Base is managing, and then you do fit inside your stating of the rule of zero.


"What should a Derived1 instance do to copy (or move from) a Derived2 instance?" This is not for Base to decide. It should copy its own members, and let the derived classes copy theirs. It might be desirable to support copying/moving one Derived1 to another.

@HolyBlackCat The design has to accommodate that

@Caleth I got it! Thank you very much. I do need to declare all five special methods as I need to mark the destructor virtual. Your perspective of considering the most derived type of object as a resource managed by the Base is truly impressive.
